# Powershell - Watch multiple folder, run multiple processes with files

Tags: powershell, foreach, hashtable, filesystemwatcher, multiple-instances

So I have a script that is setup for the following purpose:

1. If a file appears in the folder simply move it to the folder above that sub folder it has appeared in. *For example: move from c:\My_Documents\a > c:\My_Documents*
2. Every-time the above happens the file-name and the attempt number are stored in a hash table. Once the same file has appeared 3 times the file is moved to entirely different folder from the structure and an email is sent to an appropiate receiptent. *For Example: c:\My_Documents\a > c:\FailedFolder\ *

   3. The record of the file in the hash table is then removed. Also the whole hash table is cleared every 10 minutes.

This works, my issue now is that I need to expand this so that the script does this for multiple folders that are set up in exactly the same way but do not overlap. *For example: c:\My_Documents\a > c:\My_Documents\ && c:\randomFolder\a > c:\randomFolder\ && c:\AnotherRandomFolder\a > c:\AnotherRandomFolder\ *

Please can someone help me achieve this?

Please see my current code:

```
$global:folder = 'C:\Users\random\Documents\IUR Test\r' # Enter the root   path you want to monitor. 
$global:origin = 'C:\Users\random\Documents\IUR Test'
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 
$global:Failedfolder = 'C:\Users\random\Documents\Failed' 
$global:Files = @{}
$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 600000     # fire every 10 minutes
$timer.AutoReset = $true  # Enable the event again after its been fired
$timer.Enabled = $true

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $global:folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false; NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,LastWrite'} 

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier HashMapClear -Action {
    $global:Files.clear()
}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    ForEach ($file in (gci $global:folder)) 
    {
        $fName = $file.Name

        if(-not $global:Files.ContainsKey($fName))
        {
            $global:Files.Add($fName,1)             
            Move-Item $File.Fullname $global:origin -force

        }
        Elseif($global:Files.Get_Item($fName) -lt 3)
        {
            $global:Files.Set_Item($fName,++$global:Files.Get_Item($fName))             
            Move-Item $File.Fullname $global:origin -force
        }
        Else
        {
            $global:Files.Remove($fName) 
            Move-Item $File.Fullname $global:Failedfolder -force

            #### Send error email
        }
    }
} 

# To stop the monitoring, run the following commands: 
# Unregister-Event FileCreated 
# Unregister-Event HashMapClear
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to implement such thing yourself. You can use [PowershellGuard](https://github.com/smurawski/PowerShellGuard) which is very easy to use. You can also try ruby original guard if you are conformable with it which comes with bunch of plugins too.

PowershellGuard basically does what you want to, so you can see its source code for details if you want to re-implement this your own way.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve, it can be a little difficult to give you specific guidance! However, you may want to look at Powershell functions that you can call with any parameters you need (see below)

WARNING: this hasn't been run or tested :D

```
$files = @{}

$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 600000     # fire every 10 minutes
$timer.AutoReset = $true  # Enable the event again after its been fired
$timer.Enabled = $true

$email:From = 'thisisanexample@test.com'
$email:to = 'thisisanexample@test.com'
$email:Subject = 'Failed SJPM File'
$email:SMTPServer = 'thisisatest.qa.test.com'
$email:SMTPPort = 25

function sendFailureEmail([string]$filename, [string]$folder)
{
    $message = 'The file' + $filename + ' located in ' + $folder + ' has failed to process after 3 attempts, please review the file.'
    send-MailMessage -From $email:From -to $email:to -Subject $email:Subject -Body $message -SmtpServer $email:SMTPServer -port $email:SMTPPort -Cc $email:From
}

function monitorDirectory([string]$sourceDirectory, [string]$targetDirectory, [string]$failureDirectory, [string]$filter="*.*")
{
    # In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                           
    $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $sourceDirectory, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false; NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,LastWrite'} 

    Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
        ForEach ($file in (gci $sourceDirectory)) 
        {
            $fName = $file.FullName

            if(-not $files.ContainsKey($fName))
            {
                # We have not seen this file before
                $files.Add($fName, 1)               
                Move-Item $File.Fullname $targetDirectory -force

            }
            Elseif($files.Get_Item($fName) -lt 3)
            {
                # We have seen this file once or twice before
                $files.Set_Item($fName, ++$files.Get_Item($fName))              
                Move-Item $File.Fullname $targetDirectory -force
            }
            Else
            {
                # This is the third time we've seen this file, there an error has occurred
                $files.Remove($fName) 
                Move-Item $File.Fullname $failureDirectory -force

                sendFailureEmail $fName $failureDirectory
            }
        }
    } 

    $fsw
}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier HashMapClear -Action {
    # Clear the file list every x minutes
    $files.clear()
}

$f1 = monitorDirectory 'C:\Users\random\Documents\IUR Test\r' 'C:\Users\random\Documents\IUR Test' 'C:\Users\random\Documents\Failed'
$f2 = monitorDirectory 'C:\Users\random\Documents\Test2\z' 'C:\Users\random\Documents\Test2' 'C:\Users\random\Documents\Failed'

# can unregister filewatching and timers if necessary
```

Comment: I'm going to try this now. Reading the code will this work for as many folders as I specify with the $f format? I.e $f3, $f4, $f5 etc?

Comment: The idea of using a function is that you can monitor any number of folders. the $f1 and $f2 above are just variable names, this was done to allow you to stop watching the folders (if you needed to) at a later point in the script. Apologies, these variables could have been named a bit better :)

Comment: Getting the error that filesystemwatcher is already registered. I think you cannot pass multiple folders in this way.

Comment: to confirm if I comment out $f2 I can get it to compile.